# Doctrine2 ORM - delete by FK without retrieving from DB

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have two entities - UserAccounts (`user_accounts` table with `id` as PK) and BlacklistedUsers (`blacklisted_users` with `id` as PK and `user_account_id` as FK referencing to `user_accounts.id`). The challenge here is to delete the BlacklistedUsers entry by `user_accounts_id` column instead of the usual PK `id`. The important thing is that I do not want to load the entity from DB to delete it. I am also not willing to use DQL for such a simple query.

I've been trying for a while already and keep getting different errors

```
$blacklist_ref = EntityManagerContainer::get()->getPartialReference(BlacklistedUsers::class, array("user_account_id" => $user_id));
EntityManagerContainer::get()->remove($blacklist_ref);
EntityManagerContainer::get()->flush();
```

> {"errors":["Undefined index: user_account_id"]}

```
  $blacklist_ref = EntityManagerContainer::get()->getPartialReference(BlacklistedUsers::class, array("user_account" => $user_id));
  EntityManagerContainer::get()->remove($blacklist_ref);
  EntityManagerContainer::get()->flush();
```

> {"errors":["Undefined index: user_account"]}

```
  $user_ref = EntityManagerContainer::get()->getReference(UserAccounts::class, $user_id);
  $blacklist_ref = EntityManagerContainer::get()->getPartialReference(BlacklistedUsers::class, array("user_account" => $user_ref));
  EntityManagerContainer::get()->remove($blacklist_ref);
  EntityManagerContainer::get()->flush();
```

> {"errors":["Object of class DoctrineProxies\__CG__\Orm\Entity\UserAccounts could not be converted to string"]}

```
$user_ref = EntityManagerContainer::get()->getReference(UserAccounts::class, $user_id);
$blacklist_ref = EntityManagerContainer::get()->getReference(BlacklistedUsers::class, array("user_account" => $user_ref));
EntityManagerContainer::get()->remove($blacklist_ref);
EntityManagerContainer::get()->flush();
```

> {"errors":["The identifier id is missing for a query of Orm\Entity\BlacklistedUsers"]}

Can Doctrine do such a simple thing through EntityManager?

```
"delete from blacklisted_users where user_account_id = {$id}"
```